# PHP: A string, two arrays and 4 loops result in a 0

Tags: php

In my android app user can upload up to 5 images for an item they have in their collection.

This is what my android app java code is sending over to the PHP server via POST:

```
[user_id=83, 
item_id=24, 
item_number_of_photos=1, 
item_image_filename_0=http://www.asdqwe.net/item_images/83_image_2014-02-07-16-44-12.jpg,
item_image_description_0=mouse]
```

This is the PHP Code that handles it:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $user_id                = $_POST["user_id"];
    $item_id                = $_POST["item_id"];
    $item_number_of_photos  = $_POST['item_number_of_photos'];

    for ($x=0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) { 
            if(isset($_POST['item_image_filename_'.$x]) && !empty($_POST['item_image_filename_'.$x])) {
                $item_image_filenames[$x]   = $_POST['item_image_filename_'.$x];
            }
            if(isset($_POST['item_image_description_'.$x]) && !empty($_POST['item_image_description_'.$x])) {
                $item_image_descriptions[$x]    = $_POST['item_image_description_'.$x];
            } 
    } 

    $query_add_item_photos = "INSERT INTO 

                                    product_photos (
                                        product_id, 
                                        product_photo,
                                        product_photo_added_by_user,
                                        product_photo_description

                                                                )";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////ADD THE PHOTOS TO THE PHOTOS TABLE//////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    try {

        for($x = 0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) {
            $query_add_item_photos+= " VALUES 
                (

                    :product_id, 
                    :product_photo_filename_" . $x .", 
                    :product_photo_added_by_user,
                    :product_photo_description_" . $x . "
                                                )";
        }

        $input_parameters = array(
            ':product_id'                     => $item_id,
            ':product_photo_added_by_user'    => $user_id,
        );
        for($x = 0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) {
            $input_parameters[':product_photo_filename_' . $x] = $item_image_filenames[$x];
            $input_parameters[':product_photo_description_' . $x] = $item_image_descriptions[$x];
        }


        $sth = $connection->prepare($query_add_item_photos);
        $sth->execute($input_parameters);                                           
    } catch(PDOException $pe) {
        $response["success"] = $http_response_server_error;
        $response["message"] = $http_response_server_error . $pe . $query_add_item_photos;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }




    $response["success"]            = $http_response_success;
    $response["message"]            = "WE MADE IT";
    die(json_encode($response));
    $connection = null;



} else {

    $response["success"] = $http_response_bad_request;
    $response["message"] = $http_message_bad_request;
    die(json_encode($response));
    $connection = null;

}
```

At the end when I run this, I get a PDO error saying that the query = "0".
I have only basic understanding of PHP so this is huge pain for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Local Variables Issue

In your `for` loop, you are assigning values to `$item_image_filenames[$x]` array element and also to `$item_image_descriptions[$x]` array element.

```
for ($x=0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) { 
   ...
   $item_image_filenames[$x]   = $_POST['item_image_filename_'.$x];
   ...
   $item_image_descriptions[$x]    = $_POST['item_image_description_'.$x]; 
}
```

But (assuming you have posted all of your code), these 2 arrays fall out of scope and disappear as soon as you exit your `for` loop.  They weren't defined *before* your `for` loop, which means that they are being defined local to your `for` loop.

The result of this is that, later, when you attempt to reference these arrays, they don't exist, and they have no values.  So, later on in your code...

```
for($x = 0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) {
    $input_parameters[':product_photo_filename_' . $x] = $item_image_filenames[$x];
    $input_parameters[':product_photo_description_' . $x] = $item_image_descriptions[$x];
}
```

... is going to result in assigning to `$input_parameters` values that don't exist.

To solve this problem, define `$item_image_filenames` and `$item_image_descriptions` before you enter your `for` loop.  This way, they will continue to exist inside **and after** your `for` loop.  You can do this:

```
$user_id                = $_POST["user_id"];
$item_id                = $_POST["item_id"];
$item_number_of_photos  = $_POST['item_number_of_photos'];

// Define empty arrays so that I can use them throughout my code.
$item_image_filenames = array();
$item_image_descriptions = array();

for ($x=0; $x<$item_number_of_photos; $x++) { 
  ...
```

#### String Concatenation Syntax

I also noticed that your line of code:

```
$query_add_item_photos+= " VALUES 
...
```

... is not the correct way to do string concatenation in PHP.  You want to use `.=` instead of `+=`.  In PHP, strings are concatenated with `.`, as in the example: `$string1 = $string2 . $string3;`

Your code should instead be:

```
$query_add_item_photos .= " VALUES 
...
```

Comment: oh God I thought you can create a variable everywhere in the code in PHP and it would be visible... so embarrassed. thanks!

Comment: actually I did that but I get the same error. do you notice something else that is wrong with my code?

Comment: string concatenation syntax... I've edited my answer with a follow up.  In PHP, use `.` to concatenate, not `+`.